# I am trying to make a platformer, but, I don't know how to ad key controls

Tags: javascript, scripting, codesandbox

I am trying to make a platformer, but, I don't know how to ad key controls. How Do I do this?
Javascript is not for making games I know, but my IDE cant run c, c++, c#, python, and more.
it can only run javascript, typescript, and vue.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
    console.log("Up arrow key pressed");
  }
});
```